# Bootstrap tables in Moodle

Tags: css, moodle, bootstrap-table

Hi I am currently working on a client's Moodle site. We are trying to get responsive tables on the home landing page. I have not been able to copy the entire Bootstrap framework into the site as it conflicts with other Moodle libraries. I have just copied and pasted the table elements, starting from `.container` from the bootstrap CSS and added it into the Moodle custom CSS space. I've then added the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                          <tr>
                                <td class="fhcell hvr-shutter-in-horizontal" style="text-align: center;">
                                     <a href="http://moodle.ranzco.edu/course/view.php?id=98" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-medkit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><span style="font-size: x-large;"><br />Trainees</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="fhcell hvr-shutter-in-horizontal" style="text-align: center;">
                                      <p><a href="http://moodle.ranzco.edu/course/view.php?id=102" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-user-md" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br /><span style="font-size: x-large;">Term Supervisors Clinical Tutors</span></p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="fhcell hvr-shutter-in-horizontal" style="text-align: center;">
                                      <a href="http://moodle.ranzco.edu/course/view.php?id=101" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br /><span style="font-size: x-large;">Examiners</span>
                                </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td class="fhcell hvr-shutter-in-horizontal" style="text-align: center;">
                                      <a href="http://moodle.ranzco.edu/course/view.php?id=97" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br /><span style="font-size: x-large;">Mentors</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="fhcell hvr-shutter-in-horizontal" style="text-align: center;">
                                      <a href="http://moodle.ranzco.edu/course/view.php?id=100" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br /><span style="font-size: x-large;">Fellows</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="fhcell hvr-shutter-in-horizontal" style="text-align: center;">
                                      <a href="http://moodle.ranzco.edu/course/view.php?id=99" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br /><span style="font-size: x-large;">International Medical Graduates</span>
                                </td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
  </div>
```

But it's not working. Any help would be really appreciated. The site URL is [Moodle Site](http://moodle.ranzco.edu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second line `<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">` should be `<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">` there is no in col-12 in bootstrap.

Also you can [try here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp) bootstrap tables here first.

Comment: if you think this can be useful for others, you can mark my answer as useful :)